# Symfony Bootstrap Theme Doesn't Work

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap form theme in a Symfony 2.7.5 project

I added this to my app/config.yml

> ## Twig Configuration twig:
>
> ```
> form:
>   resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
>   # resources: ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig']
> ```

But my forms haven't changed. Could something be overriding the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done

```
twig:
    form:
        resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

or just

```
form:
    resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

?

Because you have to make first.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form:
        resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
        # resources: ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig']
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I've got in config.yml, but still ugly default forms

Comment: Did you do an: app/console as:du
This will create the necessary css javascript files. And also maybe: app/console as:in .And of course check if you have loaded bootstrap 3 in your layout. Otherwise you wont see it. You can use this one for testing: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: That was it! I had a mistake sourcing the css in the layout. Thanks @RayKootstra

Comment: Please mark my comments as the solution. Your welcome!